# Explicit formula for sequence where each term is the weighted average of adjacent terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, average

Consider the sequence $a_0, a_1, ..., a_{2n}$, where $a_0=0$, $a_{2n}=1$, and $a_i=wa_{i-1}+(1-w)a_{i+1}$ for all indexes $i\in [1, 2n-1]$. In other words, the first term of the sequence is 0, the last term is 1, and term in between is the weighted average of its adjacent terms.

In terms of $w$, what is $a_n$ (the middle term)? And a more general question: what is the explicit formula for each $a_i$?

Look at the cases for $n=1, 2, 3$, it seems that $a_n=\frac{w^n}{w^n+(1-w)^n}$, but unfortunately I don't know how to prove it for general $n$. Some other things I have tried to do so far is to look at it recursively and directly compute, but the terms get very ugly quickly. I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of absorption of a biased random walk when the starting point has binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294566/probability-of-absorption-of-a-biased-random-walk-when-the-starting-point-has-bi)

Comment: This is another potential duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178500/recurrence-solution-to-gamblers-ruin?noredirect=1